# Вопрос с парсингом и requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Тренируюсь на сайте спарсить авторов цитат и не могу понять из-за чего именно ошибка. Судя по коду ошибки, походу что-то не то с передаваемыми url, но что именно не знаю.

Это первый файл, который парсит:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User=Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 '
       '(.NET CLR 3.5.30729)'}


def get_url():
    links_list = []
    for count_link in range(1, 100):
        url = f'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{count_link}/'
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
        data = soup.find_all('div', class_='quote')
        result = soup.find_all('span', class_='text')
        if len(result) != 0:
            for item in data:
                link_author = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com' + item.find('a', text='(about)').get('href')
                if link_author not in links_list:
                    links_list.append(link_author)
        else:
            break
    yield links_list


def get_author():
    for url in get_url():
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

        data = soup.find('div', class_='author-details')

        name = data.find('h3', class_='author-title').text.strip()
        date_of_birth = data.find('span',  class_='author-born-date').text.strip()
        place_of_birth = data.find('span',  class_='author-born-location').text.strip()
        description_author = data.find('div', class_='author-description').text.strip()

    yield name, date_of_birth, place_of_birth, description_author
```

Это второй файл, который записывает данные в файл:

```
import xlsxwriter
from test_scrap import get_author


def writer(param):
    book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\code\test_scrap\data.xlsx')
    page = book.add_worksheet('Author')

    row = 0
    column = 0

    page.set_column('A:A', 30)
    page.set_column('B:B', 30)
    page.set_column('C:C', 30)
    page.set_column('D:E', 100)

    for item in param:
        page.write(row, column, item[0])
        page.write(row, column + 1, item[1])
        page.write(row, column + 2, item[2])
        page.write(row, column + 3, item[3])
        row += 1

    book.close()


writer(get_author())
```

А вот сам текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\code\test_scrap\writer_scrap.py", line 27, in <module>
writer(get_author())
File "C:\code\test_scrap\writer_scrap.py", line 17, in writer
for item in param:
File "C:\code\test_scrap\test_scrap.py", line 29, in get_author
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
File "C:\code\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\code\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\code\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\code\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 695, in send
adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
File "C:\code\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 792, in get_adapter
raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-K-Rowling', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jane-Austen', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Marilyn-Monroe', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Andre-Gide', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Thomas-A-Edison', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Steve-Martin', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Bob-Marley', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Dr-Seuss', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Douglas-Adams', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Elie-Wiesel', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Friedrich-Nietzsche', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Mark-Twain', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Allen-Saunders', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Pablo-Neruda', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Ralph-Waldo-Emerson', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Mother-Teresa', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Garrison-Keillor', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jim-Henson', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Charles-M-Schulz', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/William-Nicholson', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jorge-Luis-Borges', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/George-Eliot', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/George-R-R-Martin', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/C-S-Lewis', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Martin-Luther-King-Jr', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/James-Baldwin', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Haruki-Murakami', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Alexandre-Dumas-fils', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Stephenie-Meyer', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Ernest-Hemingway', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Helen-Keller', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/George-Bernard-Shaw', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Charles-Bukowski', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Suzanne-Collins', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-R-R-Tolkien', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Alfred-Tennyson', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Terry-Pratchett', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-D-Salinger', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/George-Carlin', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/John-Lennon', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/W-C-Fields', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Ayn-Rand', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Jimi-Hendrix', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/J-M-Barrie', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/E-E-Cummings', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Khaled-Hosseini', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Harper-Lee', 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Madeleine-LEngle']"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield` в функции-генераторе должен возвращать по одному элементу генерируемой последовательности, а вы в `get_url()` формируете целиком список, потом как один элемент передаете его наружу. Получается, что этот список используется как один url.

Правильно должно быть так:

```
def get_url():
    links_list = []
    for count_link in range(1, 100):
        url = f'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{count_link}/'
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
        data = soup.find_all('div', class_='quote')
        result = soup.find_all('span', class_='text')
        if len(result) != 0:
            for item in data:
                link_author = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com' + item.find('a', text='(about)').get('href')
                if link_author not in links_list:
                    yield link_author
                    links_list.append(link_author)
        else:
            break
```

Список тут используется только для того, чтобы не было дублирования элементов (хотя для этого лучше использовать `set`, а не список).

Если порядок элементов не важен, можно вообще убрать проверку на уникальность, просто в функции `get_author` обернуть вызов `get_url` в `set`:

```
for url in set(get_url()):
    ...
```

---

Из-за чего возникает проблема в вашем коде. На простом примере, как у вас сейчас:

```
def get_url():
    links_list = []
    for item in ("url1", "url2", "url3"):
        links_list.append(item)
    yield links_list


for url in get_url():
    print("url:", url)
```

Выведет:

```
url: ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
```

Т.е. цикл `for` выполнил одну итерацию, в которой в переменную `url` попал сразу весь список.

Правильно должно быть:

```
def get_url():
    for item in ("url1", "url2", "url3"):
        yield item


for url in get_url():
    print("url:", url)
```

Выведет:

```
url: url1
url: url2
url: url3
```

Также можно накапливать список, потом передавать его наружу через `yield from` вместо `yield`, но в этом нет никакого смысла, с тем же успехом можно просто возвращать список через `return`. `yield from` имеет смысл использовать для передачи наружу, например, элементов другой функции-генератора.

---

Еще одна проблема в функции `get_author`: у строки с `yield` не хватает отступа, из-за этого возвращается не каждое значение из цикла, а только последнее. Должно быть так:

```
def get_author():
    for url in get_url():
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

        data = soup.find('div', class_='author-details')

        name = data.find('h3', class_='author-title').text.strip()
        date_of_birth = data.find('span',  class_='author-born-date').text.strip()
        place_of_birth = data.find('span',  class_='author-born-location').text.strip()
        description_author = data.find('div', class_='author-description').text.strip()

        yield name, date_of_birth, place_of_birth, description_author
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог мне разобраться!)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_url():
    count_link = 1
    while True:
        url = f'https://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/life/page/{count_link}/'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
        data = soup.find_all('div', class_='quote')
        for item in data:
            yield 'https://quotes.toscrape.com' + item.find('a', text='(about)').get('href')
        if soup.find('li', class_="previous"):
            break
        count_link += 1


def get_author():
    for url in get_url():
        resp = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
        data = list(soup.find('div', class_='author-details').stripped_strings)
        name, _, date_of_birth, place_of_birth, _, description_author = data
        yield name, date_of_birth, place_of_birth, description_author


def writer():
    for item in get_author():
        print(*item, '', sep='\n')


writer()
```